# Single variable calculus: confusion about directional derivative

Tags: calculus, notation, proof-writing

I am stuck on deriving proving the following equalities: given $x,y,t$ scalar and $f$ a scalar function

(1) $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x)}{t} = \left.\dfrac{df}{dt}\right|_{t \to 0}$

(2) $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x)}{t} = f'(x + t(y-x))(y-x)$

For (1), I thought the definition of $\dfrac{df}{dt} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(t+h) - f(t)}{h}$, how does that equation to the left hand side of 1?

For (2), how does the left handside become the right hand side? It is not intuitive for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both claims are **wrong**.

Note that $x$ and $y$ are fixed in the process. If $x=y$ then obviously
$$\lim_{t\to0}{f\bigl(x+t(y-x)\bigr)-f(x)\over t}=0\ .$$
When $x\ne y$ then
$$ {f\bigl(x+t(y-x)\bigr)-f(x)\over t}={f\bigl(x+t(y-x)\bigr)-f(x)\over t(y-x)}\cdot(y-x)$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{t\to0}{f\bigl(x+t(y-x)\bigr)-f(x)\over t}=\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\cdot(y-x)=f'(x)\cdot(y-x)\ .\tag{1}$$
A posteriori we can verify that $(1)$ holds also when $x=y$.